# Makefile: get short version string from version string

Tags: makefile

How to get the short version string from the version string in Makefile? Suppose the short version string is got by `sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]$//g' $version`.

```
version=v3.2.11
version_short=$(patsubst %.11,%,$(version))
print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
all: print-version_short
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't list GNU make in your tags but your makefile is clearly GNU make so I'll respond in kind.

If you know there are always exactly two "."s it can be done like this:

```
combine = $(word 1,$1).$(word 2,$1)

short := $(call combine,$(subst ., ,$(version)))
```

This converts the "." to spaces then calls a user-defined function with the resulting arguments, which puts back together the first two arguments.

Comment: I tried your Makefile in Linux. The result `short = v3 2 11.` is not as expected.